# How to get a receipt when scanning my card on Tel Aviv buses?

Tags: buses, israel

Some buses in the Tel Aviv area (and possibly the Jerusalem area and other places) let you just scan your Rav Kav (smart bus card) when entering from any door, with no driver interaction. These machines don't seem to print receipts.

I occasionally need to present the actual travel receipts. How do I get my receipt from this kind of payment?

In some cases there are two options -- self serve and at the driver -- and the driver prints receipts. But on some buses there's only one option.

Comment: Check with your travel department.  I've never worked for or known anyone who's worked for a company that requires a receipt for an amount as small as bus fare.  Either way, they have to have a process to handle expenses without receipts.

Comment: @Johns-305 I'm supposed to get passes to ride for free from the army but occasionally don't get, so I need to submit the receipts and they refund me.

Comment: You should get a receipt when spending money, not when discharging your Rav Kav card. And you do, every time you charge it it's at a machine that can print a receipt. This is the one you should give your employer.

Comment: @ytoledano As i said in the comment above, i'm supposed to get free rides from the army, but occasionally have to pay and submit the receipts for refunding. That's on each individual usage of the Rav Kav.

Comment: Does the card has an online option to see where/when you used your card? In my country that is the only option to get proof of where and when you used your card and you hand a print of that in to get the refund.

Comment: A RavKav card is _required_ to ride on Tel Aviv buses (the buses I was one did not take cash), and the cards are useable but not required on Jerusalem buses, as of 1/2019.  I got an anonymous card on a bus (for 5 shekels plus the cost of the ticket) and then had to refill the card at a local market.  More info is here: http://www.egged.co.il/Article-786-Rav-Kav-Card.aspx#1

Answer (score 6):

You cannot get a receipt for a single fare.
You can get a receipt from a Rav-Kav issued by a specific service (the train, Egged, etc.) for the entire purchase, e.g. if you purchased a 50 NIS top-off to your card.

If you need it for a record, a driver can print the last few rides you made with the card, but he/she does not have to - it's for dispute clarification purposes only.

Comment: "You cannot get a recipt for a single fare." -- in this specific case? Because generally you can.

Comment: The specific case refers to "...let you just scan your Rav Kav (smart bus card) when entering from any door...". So no ticket is printed or can be printed.

Using Rav-Kav with loaded money (not a contract) at the driver cashier, will produce a fare ticket.